# Bouncing Truth level

Tags: vvvvvv

In VVVVVV, how can I beat the level with the two TRUTH words bouncing up and down? They are perfectly opposite each other's bounce, and the platform to run on disappears too quickly.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To get past this level, it is all about timing.

As to when to run?

> Start running just before the "TRUTH" on the left touches the spikes from its ascend, and keep holding the right button until you are underneath the second truth. By then, it should be just touching the spikes from an ascend. Flip and keep running til' you get into the nook on the other side.
> If you are going a little faster than the two "TRUTH" and keep running into the second "TRUTH", take a short pause underneath the first "TRUTH" to give the second "TRUTH" time to head back up.
>
>  Just a warning, let go of the right button just before you reach the wall, otherwise you'll just 'walk' into the spikes on the other side.